# REST-ful Workflow Service with .NET 4.0

Tags: rest, workflow-foundation, workflowservice

With WCF, we can create services that can accept leverage HTTP POST and simple accept an XElement as it's parameter. I'd like to do something similar with a workflow service so that I can use jQuery to post an xml infoset to a service, have it run through a bunch of rules and then return an xml infoset.

With a WCF service, I can simply decorate the operation w/ WebInvoke and go on my merry way. Is it possible to use WebInvoke w/ a Workflow Service and if so, how should I go about?

Answer (score 0):

Workflow services are currently tied to traditional WCF SOAP.  You cannot use the WCF REST API (i.e., the WebHttp binding) with WF 4 currently.